# How to read a csv table where some rows contain "\n" in R

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I am trying to read a csv file that I created in R. 
Some rows contain the following character name:
"Drug a + Drug B \n Drug C + Drug D"

When I want to read it, I do not have the part after the \n and additionnal rows with NA are added. So my question is simple, how can I read csv file where some rows contain "\n"?

Thanks for your help

Aziz

Comment: That is probably not the two characters, backslash and n, its probably an end-of-line character, but it should show as a new line when you list a text file - how are you displaying that? How exactly did you create the file in the first place?

Comment: Well, I used a software to perform some simulations. This software gave me an output table that I modified in R. So I have a column with time, the variable, the patient ID. I added the protocol column as shown above. To register the table in a csv file, I used the following command: write.table(Data, file="Tumorb2_RV5.csv", sep=",", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)